Question on conditional formatting from another sheet using "VlookUP","Year","IFerror"
I have a Google sheet table which likes this named ‘Sheet 2’



Phone
CNo






xxx
a
b
c


yyy
d
e
f



another table like this named ‘Phone 1’



CNo
Year




a
1753-01-01


b
1753-01-01


c
2019-09-13


d
2020-12-11


e
2024-09-22


f
2016-04-22



I want to check if the Year of the CNo is > 2019, if yes, the box will show green, if no remains unchanged.
However, when I tried to use this formula in the conditional formatting it returns an error. What should I do?
=IFERROR(Year(Vlookup(E1,'Phone 1'!$B$2:$C$26036,2,false))>=2019,false)


Conditional formatting rules cannot refer to other sheets directly. Use indirect(), like this:
=vlookup(E1, indirect("Phone 1!B2:C"), 2, false) >= 2019

The formula assumes that column 'Phone 1'!C2:C contains numbers like 2019. If the column contains dates like 2019-01-01 instead, use this:
=year(vlookup(E1, indirect("Phone 1!B2:C"), 2, false)) >= 2019

There is usually no need to mask errors in a conditional formatting rule. Errors get the same result as false — no formatting gets applied.

How about if the date is like this 2019-01-01??

I have tried to use the formula in the conditional formatting, however it returns the same error. When I tried to use this in cell, It said the current value of “function:indirect”, Parameter:1 id “”. This is not a valid cell/range reference.

I've tried this formula in conditional formatting and it works without any error. FYI, I selected cell "E1" on the first sheet (val = "CNo"), Conditional formatting, "Range"=> E1:E3, "Format cells if"=> "Custom formula", "formula"=> =year(vlookup(E1, indirect("Phone 1!B2:C"), 2, false)) >= 2019. Cell E3 (value = "d"-equivalent year = 2020) is the ONLY cell to have background colour of green. Sounds like your indirect formula is failing; suggest you test it alone. Enter this =indirect("Phone 1!B2:C") in any cell on any sheet other than "Phone 1".

I am not sure but it returns with an error #Ref!. even if I only tried =indirect("Phone 1!B2:C").  I have make some changes on the table. The second table is the Phone 1 actually. and I would like to do the conditional formatting on the first table

The sheet name is correctly spelled cause I can see that it has the correct color on the phone 1 sheet when i tried to clicked on the sheet name in indirect

I have created a sample sheet with link https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14dopzLvgV43JwmZaX2sAXfIHJzT-mVaFFdXkQ07Edco/edit
and it returns the same error

The formula I gave you seems to work fine. There is a typo in the snippet you tried. =INDIRECT(Sheet1!B2:C) is not the same as =indirect("Sheet1!B2:C"). I have pasted the conditional formatting rule in Sheet2 and the colors are coming through OK.

Oh, That's why I keep not getting the correct one. Thank you. I thought =INDIRECT(Sheet1!B2:C) is same as =indirect("Sheet1!B2:C"). Thank you.
